# Verilog nested "if" semantics

Tags: verilog

What is the difference between the following two code blocks? When I implement and run them, I get different results. But per my personal understanding, they should be semantically identical.

```
M_state_d = M_state_q;
M_mx_d = M_mx_q;

V1
-----
      PUSH_READ_state: begin
        if ((&M_ctr_q)) begin
          if ((&M_mx_q)) begin
            M_state_d = POP_state;
            M_mx_d = 1'h0;
          end
          M_state_d = PUSH_state;
        end
      end

V2
-----
      PUSH_READ_state: begin
        M_state_d = ((&M_ctr_q) && (&M_mx_q)) ? POP_state : ((&M_ctr_q) ? PUSH_state : M_state_q);
        M_mx_d = ((&M_ctr_q) && (&M_mx_q)) ? 1'h0 : M_mx_q;
      end
```

EDIT:

Okay so I changed V1 to

```
      PUSH_READ_state: begin
        if ((&M_ctr_q)) begin
          M_state_d = PUSH_state;   // I MOVED THIS
          if ((&M_mx_q)) begin
            M_state_d = POP_state;
            M_mx_d = 1'h0;
          end
        end
      end
```

And the behavior becomes the same. Why is this?

Comment: they look identical to me. However, if you have different results, you need to provide more code which could demonstrate your issues and also expected and produced results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens in your original code when `&M_ctr_q && &M_mx_q`. Both of the assignments to `M_state_d` will take place:

```
PUSH_READ_state: begin
        if ((&M_ctr_q)) begin
          if ((&M_mx_q)) begin
            M_state_d = POP_state;  // <- Assignment 1
            M_mx_d = 1'h0;
          end
          M_state_d = PUSH_state;   // <- Assignment 2
        end
      end
```

In other words, when `&M_ctr_q` is true, you will always be assigning `M_state_d = PUSH_state` due to the order of assignments (last one wins with blocking assignments).

Your V1 code update is one solution to avoid the issue, but you might prefer to make the assignments more clearly exclusive (that is, use `else`):

```
PUSH_READ_state: begin
        if ((&M_ctr_q && &M_mx_q)) begin
          M_state_d = POP_state;
          M_mx_d = 1'h0;
        end
        else if (&M_ctr_q) begin
          M_state_d = PUSH_state;
        end
      end
```